# Store and fetch chat messages in text file Java

Tags: java

How do I store chat messages in a Text File in Java and then fetch them later when needed
Also is xml better solution for this

Comment: "better" depends on what you're trying to do. The format of your text file also depends on the contents of these chat messages. Please provide more information.

Comment: Only information i need to store is the name of the user followed by the text message and maybe a timestamp too

Comment: Well, where are your data coming from? AIM? XMPP? A chat system you built yourself? How are you interfacing with the chat software?

Comment: I am using the Atmosphere framework which is a java servlet based chat system. I am using it in web application , so data is coming from a webpage through ajax

Comment: Are you going to "append" data to this file?  Do you need to support multiple threads reading and writing at the same time?  If the answer to these are yes, then a file isn't really a good choice.  You'll want a database of some sort that can handle this efficiently for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is probably a "better" solution for this since you're fairly certain of the structure of your data. You could use something like the SAXParser to be able to read-in the messages fairly easily. Though I would suggest using a database because your file could grow really fast.

Comment: How can I store it in database I would have to use one row per message i think which will make it very large

Comment: The overhead of a database would be much smaller than XML. Additionally, appending to an XML file is not very efficient.

Comment: @Sumit Jain - On the contrary, the database is designed to hold huge volumes of data. It is also more extensible, say for instance you may need to provide a user with a summary of all the messages they have sent/has been sent to them, it's easy to do that with a database, but it could get very intensive if you try that with an XML file.